# iOS picker inside of a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, picker

Have a fun one here

I've got a `UIPickerView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`, theses weren't meant to be used this way were they?

So far the picker slides up on click but there's no data in the picker and the done/cancel buttons are not showing up.

Does anybody know if this is possible or know a better way to do it? Here's the code (just trying to get it to work for now)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UIViewController{
    fileprivate var presenter: HelloworkJobsEditJobPresenter?

    @IBOutlet weak var editJobTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIView!


    func inject(presenter: HelloworkJobsEditJobPresenter) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    var helloworkJob: HelloworkJob!

    let labelData = ["Title","Company",
                     "Location","Job Type",
                     "Min Salary","Max Salary",
                     "Posted Date"]

    let pickerData = ["Full Time", "Part Time", "Casual",
                      "Fixed term","Shiftworkers",
                      "Daily hire and weekly hire",
                      "Probation","Outworkers"]

    var myPicker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    var pickerTextField: UITextField?
    var picker: UIPickerView?
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()


    var textFieldData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        helloworkJob = presenter?.getHelloworkJob()
        editJobTable.dataSource = self
        editJobTable.delegate = self
        prepareTextFieldData()
        blurBackgroundButton()
        //setUpPickerView()
    }

    func setUpPickerView(){
        picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.width, height:300))
        picker!.backgroundColor = .white

        picker!.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        picker!.delegate = self
        picker!.dataSource = self

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector("donePicker"))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector("donePicker"))

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    func setPickerTextField(pickerTextField:UITextField){
        setUpPickerView()
        pickerTextField.inputView = picker
        pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }


    func blurBackgroundButton(){
        if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
            blurView.backgroundColor = .clear

            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            //always fill the view
            blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

            blurView.addSubview(blurEffectView) //if you have more UIViews, use an insertSubview API to place it where needed
        }
    }

    func prepareTextFieldData(){
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.jobTitle)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.companyName)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.jobLocation)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.jobType)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.minSalary)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.maxSalary)
        textFieldData.append(helloworkJob.jobDatePosted)
    }

    @IBAction func tapCloseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        print("click received")
//        if(indexPath.row == 3){
//            print("pass 3")
//            pickerTextField!.resignFirstResponder()
//        }
    }

}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("\(#line): \(#function) \(indexPath.row)")


        if(indexPath.row == 3){
            let cellIdentifier = "CommonLabelPickerCell"
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CommonLabelPickerCell else {
                fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of \(cellIdentifier).")
            }

            cell.cellLabel.text = labelData[indexPath.row]
            pickerTextField = cell.pickerTextField
            setPickerTextField(pickerTextField: pickerTextField!)
            return cell
        }else{
            let cellIdentifier = "CommonLabelTextFieldCell"
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CommonLabelTextFieldCell else {
                fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of \(cellIdentifier).")
            }

            cell.cellLabel.text = labelData[indexPath.row]
            cell.cellTextField.text = textFieldData[indexPath.row]
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate{

}
extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource{
    // The number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        // not being called
        print(pickerData)
        return pickerData[row]
    }
}
```

The Table Cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CommonLabelPickerCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!

    //MARK: Properties
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: see this link for better idea: http://www.thomashanning.com/how-to-show-and-hide-a-date-picker-from-a-table-view-cell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest using [IQDropDownTextField](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField) library which supports TextField with DropDown using UIPickerView.

Follow the below steps to set up and use **IQDropDownTextField**

1. Add pod to project Podfile `pod 'IQDropDownTextField'`
2. install pod by executing `pod install` on the terminal
3. Add the .h file in your bridging header and import to `HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController` with `#import "IQDropDownTextField.h"`
4. set class of text field `var pickerTextField: IQDropDownTextField!`
5. In `viewDidLoad()` setup

   `pickerTextField.isOptionalDropDown = false 
   pickerTextField.itemList = pickerData`

Cheers!